# Convert a column of type varchar(255) to type date in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sqldatetime

I'm a new in SQL and I'm trying to convert a column of type `varchar(255)` to `datetime` (yyyy-mm-dd). I found some advice to convert one element but how can I convert entire column to a new datatype?

My table is `mydemo` and the column to convert is `ordertime` and it contains only valid datetime strings lie this:

- 2021-05-13
- 2021-05-12
- 2021-05-10

Could someone please help me?

Comment: First there is no Postgres version 4.2.18. Please correct to actual version. That can be found by doing `select version()`. Second does `ordertime` have only datetime strings in it? Third do you want to convert column in place or create a new column? Add the answers to the previous ad update to your question. Lastly please do not use  images to present data, instead use text.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thank you, i adready update my question.

Comment: Do you want date **and** time or only a date? Your current values are date only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if all the rows have valid datetime values you can do it using command below:

```
alter table mydemo
alter column ordertime type timestamp USING ordertime::timestamp without time zone;
```